# Инлайн-Боты в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, inline

Всем привет, недавно столкнулся с такой задачей, подсмотрел идею в @vostickbot.
[image: Сама задача]

Дело в том, что когда я вывожу список данных аудио(на ios и Web они отображаются немного по-другому, но это все равно аудио, которые на android можно послушать прямо в списке), в отправляемых CachedVoice или просто Voice нет поля description, которое идет сразу после названия аудио(title).

*на данном изображении title=Ля ты крыса, а description=Демис Карибидис и.т.д*

**В своем проекте, я тоже хочу отображать список аудио, но никак не могу понять, как добавить туда описание. Пожалуйста помогите. Использовал все, что есть в интернете, сразу говорю, что caption или input_message_content не выполняют данное требование**

Answer (score 0):

description не используется в aio
Попробуй через `performer` либо через `caption`:

```
result = InlineQueryResultAudio(
    id='1',
    audio_url='https://example.com/audio.mp3',
    title='Название аудио',
    performer='Исполнитель',
    audio_duration=120,
    caption='Описание аудио',
    parse_mode='HTML',
    caption_entities=[],
    reply_markup=None,
    input_message_content=None,
    thumb_url='https://example.com/audio_thumb.jpg',
    thumb_width=320,
    thumb_height=240
)
```

В `python-telegram-bot` можно использовать `description`:

```
from telegram import InlineQueryResultAudio, InputTextMessageContent

result = InlineQueryResultAudio(
    id='1',
    audio_url='http://example.com/audio.mp3',
    title='Название аудио',
    caption='Описание аудио',
    parse_mode='MarkdownV2',
    caption_entities=[{'type': 'bold', 'offset': 0, 'length': 7}],
    performer='Исполнитель',
    audio_duration=120,
    reply_markup=None,
    input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent('Текст при отправке аудио'),
    thumb_url='http://example.com/thumb.jpg',
    thumb_width=512,
    thumb_height=512,
    description='Дополнительное описание аудио'
)
```

не по теме, не понимаю зачем минусовать сообщение, лучше-бы ответили.